# Expose all ports for a Docker image

Tags: docker

I am troubleshooting a solution in which I am setting up a HA cluster. Although I know the ports needed for the application to perform failover and failback, somehow the dockerized solution is not working. I suspect that there are some ports that I do not know about yet.

Currently, my `EXPOSE` statement says:

```
EXPOSE 8080 61616 5672 61613 5445 1883
```

I also start my docker containers with

```
docker run --network host -p 8080:8080 -p 61616:61616 -p 5672:5672 -p 61613:61613 -p 5445:5445 -p 1883:1883
```

But for the sake of troubleshooting, I want to expose ALL ports.

I tried something like:

```
EXPOSE 1-65535
```

But this gives an ERROR.

What is the best way I can expose ALL ports of the docker container?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When running using `--network host` there is no need to map the ports. All the docker container ports will be available since the network host mode makes the container use the host's network stack.

Also the `EXPOSE 8080 61616 5672 61613 5445 1883` is not needed. This instruction doesn't do anything. It is just a way to document which ports need to be mapped.

In short, running `docker run --network host ...` will expose all the container ports.

Comment: By some reason, this option does not work on Mac (macOS: 10.15.7, Docker engine 19.03.13). Though it's OK on Linux machine. Just keep in mind.

Comment: It's not broken, this feature is not implemented on Mac and Windows

Answer (score 11):

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.

More information on [the Docker documentation portal](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).

Answer (score 4):

Using `host` networking will expose almost all the ports just like you're running the application in the host machine. If port flags are used when running in host networking mode, those flags are ignored with a warning

> Note: Given that the container does not have its own IP-address when using host mode networking, port-mapping does not take effect, and the -p, --publish, -P, and --publish-all option are ignored, producing a warning instead:

```
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode
```

Make sure your host is a Linux host because host networking is only supported by Linux hosts.

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.

This is mentioned in Docker documentation it self. [View particular Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)