# NGINX listen on dynamic port for docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, http, nginx, socket.io

I have a web app which creates a docker container on a HTTP request and exposes a port dynamically. This port runs a NodeJS web app running `socket.io`, so how can I make this NodeJS web app accessible over my domain name?

Answer (score 0):

If you know your ports range you can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28721643/4356470) to allow container expose specific range of ports
Check out below sample

```
docker run --expose=5000-8000
```

But if you don't know range of ports that your application is running on in my opinion you need to allow all ports expose to your container
check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49323975/4356470)

Comment: Yes I can expose the port but how can I connect to the same using my domain? What'll be the NGINX configuration? Any idea?

Comment: you can use nginx as a LoadBalancer and put your range port in configuration check out this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/279262/nginx-proxy-a-large-port-range-to-equivalent-port-on-a-different-ip-address)