# Dask error running inside container: "Shut down workers that don't have promised key"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dask

I have two docker containers running on separate AWS instances. One container houses the dask-scheduler. The other host runs a container that launches the dask-worker.
I am able to connect the two with proper VPC configurations and port sharing of the container.
The worker appears to be connecting to the scheduler as the scheduler and worker reports the correct information. I provided flag --contact-address with the IP of the AWS instance that the worker container is running on.

Worker shows: Registered to tcp://scheduler-ip
Scheduler shows: "Starting worker compute stream, tcp://worker-ip>"

I can launch the dask console and view the worker connected as well.

When I submit tasks with the python client call, the tasks appear on the dask scheduler as expected, however the tasks are only in memory and do not begin processing. After some time, dask times out and provided error back:

"Error - Couldn't gather keys {'dask_node_name': ['tcp://worker-ip'], ..."

I have executed the same code base using two containers on a single host without issue. I'm wondering if dask does not like this architecture and possibly a different architecture is needed. Or, since dask is complaining for a specific "key", possibly my dag requires a key pair with the worker IP? That would seem odd to me since I can't always know the IP in advance and doesn't work for scaling.

When I review the dask code base for this error, it is not very informative.

Comment: It looks like a network problem, could you share the commands you used to setup this cluster? There should be no problem with deploying a Dask Distributed cluster on two instances using containers, as long as network setup is right.

Comment: Correct. I added "--network host" and everything went through. Possibly I wasn't passing enough ports through, not sure. But I do not need to restrict the container on the instance, so I'm fine sharing the host network entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used option "--network host" with the docker run command to share the host network with the container rather than trying the -p to share port ranges and it works.

Credit to this answer [Expose all ports for a Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323225/expose-all-ports-for-a-docker-image)