# Unable to access jenkins on port 8080 when running docker network host

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a Jenkins running in a docker container in Linux ec2 instance. I am running testcontainers within it and I want to expose all ports to the host. For that I am using network host.

When I run the jenkins container with -p 8080:8080 everything works fine and I am able to access jenkins on {ec2-ip}:8080

```
docker run id -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

however, If I want to run the same image using --network=host as I want to expose all ports to the host

```
docker run id --network=host jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

{ec2-ip}:8080 becomes unreachable. I can curl to it locally within the container localhost:8080 but accessing jenkins from the browser doesn't work.

I am not sure how network host would change the way I access jenkins on port 8080. the application should be still available on port 8080 on the host IP address?

Comment: You shouldn't normally need `--network=host`.  If the `docker run -p` option works (and I'd expect it would for straightforward Web applications like Jenkins), that's a better approach and you should just use that.

Comment: Agreed. But problem is I am using testcontainers like postgres for integration test and these test containers come up on random ports. My understanding is network host will allow me to connect to those containers otherwise how can I allow to publish on random ports?

Comment: At least for Java Testcontainers, there is a `getHost()` method that returns the host name or IP address where the container can be reached.  This is not necessarily `localhost` but Testcontainers is aware of most of the common variations.

Comment: Correct. I do use the getHost and it is 172.17.0.1.
without --network=host I get connection refused on 172.17.0.1:4951 or any other port for that matter. When I use network host I am able to connect to the testcontainer but I cannot bring up the jenkins UI on port 8080. I tried different lunix EC2 instances and it works fine so I am guessing it is something to do with the existing ec2 instance setup.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you are enabling the port 8080 in the security group for the instance.

When a Docker container is running in the host network mode using the --**network=host** option, it shares the network stack with the Docker host. This means that the container is not isolated and uses the same network interface as the host.

In your case, you should be able to access the Jenkins from the browser with ec2-ip:8080

I tested it by running Jenkins with the following command:

```
docker run -id --name jenkins --network=host jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

if the issue still persists, you can check the following:

- make sure the container is running
- make sure that there is no other process is running on port 8080
- make sure that you enabled the port 8080 for your ec2

Comment: Yes I have checked all of the above. If there was a security group issue then I don't think I would of been able to connect on port 8080 when using --p 8080:8080 and there are no other processes running on port 8080. I feel it is something to do with the instance because I am using an existing linux ec2 that someone already created but when I launch another ec2 I get no issues with running network host

Comment: Make sure you added the user to the docker group to be able to access the host's network.

i tested it by doing the following:
1- created new ec2 instance
2- created a new user with: sudo useradd test
3- addedd test user to docker group:  sudo usermod -aG docker test
4- switch to user and test. it worked with me with two diff apps ( grafana and jenkins)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU `--network` doesn't do what you expect it to do. `--network` flag allows you to connect the container to a network. For example, when you do `--nerwork=host` your container will be able to use the Docker host network stack. Not the other way around. Take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings).

Comment: I agree. but I am trying to solve for a similar problem to this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323225/expose-all-ports-for-a-docker-image

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. needed to update iptables to allow port 8080 on network host.

```
sudo iptables -D INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -m comment --comment "# jenkins #" -j ACCEPT
```